# Getting std::bad_alloc save as NE_100m_land to EPSG3995 for reprojection from QGIS?

Tags: coordinate-system, qgis-3

I have loaded ne_110m_land.shp into a new project in QGIS 3.4 running on Mac. I followed what seems to be the sequence in every tutorial to reproject this map. In this case I want to project the map to an Arctic Sterographic projection.

I have done the following (and some more options before I started noting tham)

- Right click ne_110m_land
- Click export
- Click 'save features as' - This brings up the correct dialogue box.
- Format: I have tried Geopackage and ESRI shapefile
- File name: I give the file name MI2 and folder for it to go to. (I have tried both an empty, new folder and putting this file in with the other ne_110m files)
- CRS: I select EPSG3995 WGS84 Arctic Polar Stereographic
  Add saved file to map is ticked
- Click OK.

I get the dialogue box std::bad_alloc
The layer appears to be added, but the map is the original, except glitchy.

If I do not add saved file to map there is no glitchiness. If I close the current project and open the saved file I also get the dialogue box std::bad_alloc. If I reopen the ne_110m_land file after trying to open MI2, it is glitchy in the same way. I must restart QGIS to get the file to display properly again.

I tried downloading 3.8 and the same happened.

I have tried with version 2 and version 4 of the ne_110m_land files and the same happened.

I tried different coding (alternatives to UTF-8) with no difference

I tried Stereographic World and it seems to have worked as it should in the tutorials.

Triton North Pole Stereographic resulted in an openable file, which does center on the North pole, but it is very strange.

[image: Weird Triton North Pole Stereographic result]

I finally was able to get EPSG 102035 North Pole Orthographic to work.

Is the issue with EPSG3995 WGS84 Arctic Polar Stereographic a bug?

Or is this somehow an inappropriate choice in a way I don't understand?

Is Triton North Pole also a bug or an inappropriate option for reprojection in a way I haven't understood?

Comment: did you clip the layer to just the polar region (or even northern hemisphere) before reprojection? I would expect Antarctica to go to infinite area and probably break if not. Though it should give a better error message anyway

Comment: Thank you for your reply Ian. I didn't think to clip it. I can't figure out how to do that now though to test if that was the issue. I created a shapefile layer and drew a polygon of the northern hemisphere. I tried then vector > geoprocessing tools > clip and used the ne110m layer as the input layer, and the polygon as the overlay layer, but I get the error: "Feature (78) has invalid geometry. Please fix the geometry or change the Processing setting to the "Ignore invalid input features" option.
Execution failed after 0.03 seconds"
I can't find where to change the processing setting.

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to contain clarifications. Given corrupt input detection, this should be the focus of the question (Garbage in, garbage out).

Comment: Where is the corrupt input detection?

Comment: "Feature (78) has invalid geometry."

Comment: Ok. That is only when I tried to see about clipping in response to Ian Turton's suggestion. That was not something I tried before/during all the steps listed in the question above. So invalid geometry of the polygon I tried to clip with is not the cause of the problems with reprojection above, but that I failed to clip the image may be. I need to learn more about how to drive QGIS before I can test that properly.